# Highcharts custom formatting/coloring of category labels

Tags: highcharts

I need to be able to apply background coloring (and text coloring to maintain contrast) to category labels.

I couldn't find an easy way to set each category label independently and came up with a working solution but now the width of my label column is too wide and applying marginLeft doesn't work.

First is there an easier way to achieve what I want or a solution to the width.

Here's the result:
[image]

and fiddle can be found [here](https://jsfiddle.net/alpic80/uwd2x1vt/)

```
    Highcharts.ganttChart('container', {

  chart: {
//  marginLeft: 400,
    events: {
      load: function() {
        for (var tickPos in this.yAxis[0].ticks) {
          console.log(tickPos);
          var ch = this.yAxis[0].chart;
          var tick = this.yAxis[0].ticks[tickPos];
          var label = tick.label;
          if (typeof label !== "undefined") {
            var text = label.textStr;
            var obj = JSON.parse(text);
            var element = label.element;
            element.textContent = obj.name;
            if (typeof obj.background !== "undefined") {
              element.style["background-color"] = obj.background;
            }
            if (typeof obj.color !== "undefined") {
              element.style["color"] = obj.color;
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  title: {
    text: 'Highcharts Gantt Chart'
  },

  subtitle: {
    text: 'With linked to split'
  },

  xAxis: {
    minPadding: 0.05,
    maxPadding: 0.05
  },
  "yAxis": [{
    "scrollbar": {
      "enabled": true
    },
    labels: {
      useHTML: true
    },
    "uniqueNames": true
  }],
  tooltip: {
    outside: true
  },
  rangeSelector: {
    enabled: true,
    selected: 5
  },
  time: {
    useUTC: true
  },
  plotOptions: {
    column: {
      grouping: true
    }
  },

  "series": [{
    "name": "main",
    "tooltip": {
      "headerFormat": null
    },
    "data": [{
      "name": '{"name": "Color prep and printing", "background":"green", "color":"white"}',
      "id": "_dqbcsMWXEeeTdKTuQU2hRA",
      "start": 1577836800000,
      "end": 1582934400000,

      "color": {
        "patternIndex": 0
      }
    }, {
      "name": '{"name": "Send to color house", "background":"blue", "color":"white"}',
      "id": "_dqkmv8WXEeeTdKTuQU2hRA",
      "parent": "_dqbcsMWXEeeTdKTuQU2hRA",
      "start": 1577836800000,
      "end": 1580428800000,
      "duration": 30
    }, {
      "name": '{"name": "Generate proofs", "background":"teal", "color":"white"}',
      "id": "_dq3hkMWXEeeTdKTuQU2hRA",
      "parent": "_dqbcsMWXEeeTdKTuQU2hRA",
      "start": 1578614400000,
      "end": 1579651200000,
      "duration": 12,
      "dependency": [{
        "to": "_dqkmv8WXEeeTdKTuQU2hRA"
      }]
    }, {
      "name": '{"name": "Print and ship", "background":"crimson"}',
      "id": "_drLDlcWXEeeTdKTuQU2hRA",
      "parent": "_dqbcsMWXEeeTdKTuQU2hRA",
      "start": 1581292800000,
      "end": 1582934400000,
      "duration": 19,
      "dependency": [{
        "to": "_dq3hkMWXEeeTdKTuQU2hRA"
      }]
    }],
    "dataLabels": [{}, {
      "enabled": true,
      "align": "right",
      "format": "{point.duration}"
    }]
  }],
});
```

Comment: Hi @Alain P, No, you need to change the colors in that way. To increase the width, you can set `width` style, example: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/nkz9xmh0/

Comment: Fantastic, thanks so much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To increase the width, you can set `width` style:

```
yAxis: {
    labels: {
        useHTML: true,
        style: {
            width: '300px',
            textOverflow: 'ellipsis'
        }
    },
    ...
},
```

---

**Live demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/nkz9xmh0/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/gantt/yAxis.labels.style

Comment: Well it doesn't seem to work reliably in all cases. Now with a full set of data I see that the width is applied to the label (as it says) but not to the "column". See https://jsfiddle.net/alpic80/v37rmn56/

Comment: Hi @Alain P, You can also set the width in this way: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/m7ud3s2z/

Comment: Good to know, but this again sets the width of the label and not the width of the "column". Change it to 200 for example and the column itself doesn't change width.

Comment: Sorry for misunderstanding, To change the width of the column additionally set: `textOverflow: 'ellipsis'`. Example: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/m7ud3s2z/1/

Comment: That does it. For anyone interested here, if you expand/collapse the tree node it will fail, you need to apply the same logic to the redraw event.